# why i am getting Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited.?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-database

I am getting this error when I am trying to add data on the auction_watching model. I tried make ManytoMany relation with **auction_watching** and **products** table. But why I am getting this error. Please help me out

**`models.py`**

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Products(models.Model):
    product_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Products, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        img=Image.open(self.product_img.path)
        if img.height >= 300 and img.width >=300:
            img = img.resize((200, 300)) # resize use to resize image, don't care about ration
            # output_size = (200,300)
            # img.thumbnail(output_size) # thumbnail use to resize image with aspect ration
            img.save(self.product_img.path)
class Auction_Watching(models.Model):
    product_info = models.ManyToManyField(Products, null=True )
    User_id = models.IntegerField()
    current_bid = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    action_status = models.BooleanField(default='True')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

***views.py***

```
def auction_watch(request,pk):
    username=request.session['username']
    user_id= request.session['value']
    product_information = Products.objects.get(id=pk)
    product_watch = Auction_Watching.objects.create(product_info=product_information, User_id=user_id)
    return render(request, 'auctionApp/auction_watch.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research i got the answer of my own questions.
in django we can't assign value direct in ManyToMany fields like:
`product_watch = Auction_Watching.objects.create(product_info=product_information, User_id=user_id)`

here project_info in ManyToMany field and I inserted value directly which django is not allowing. Instead we need to do: first we need to fetch all the value of that table in a variable like:
`product_description = Products.objects.get(id=pk)`
Then create value in table without this ManyToMany field like: `product_watch = Auction_Watching.objects.create(User_id=user_id)`. then add ManyToMany field in next line like: `product_watch.product_info.add(product_description)`, you don't need to use save().